# How to remove padding in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Is there a way to remove the left padding, between the Y-axis and the first value in C3.js? If so, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs, it looks like you can add an [axis.x.padding](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-padding) setting, like so:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnp4de61/ (the padding stuff near the top of the code apparently for the overall chart within the page).