# Adding c3.js padding without cutting off points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'd removed padding from my chart, but therefore got another problem - my text is cut off.

I understand, that it is not possible to show first point and text ( due to Y line axis), I would like to remove text from first point and first point appear above OY line - how it's possible?

Another question - how to solve problem with cutting last point?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If padding isn't doing what you want, you could try this bit of css:

```
.c3-texts .c3-text:first-child {
  text-anchor: start;
}

.c3-texts .c3-text:last-child {
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

This should keep the first and last labels within the confines of the chart

Answer (score 0):

```
axis: {
    x: {
        padding: {
            left: 0.1,
            right: 0.1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add this axis config in your chart creating configuration, you can change the padding to fit your needs.

Comment: Please refer to the following fiddle, try changing the padding and check.

If it still does not work for you, please send your chart generating configuration.

https://jsfiddle.net/dhvsandeep/2hpfvm32/6/

Comment: Padding to the chart is different from padding to the axis. Anyway you have to adding padding to the  axis to show the value on the data point.

Comment: In your example you have whitespace between chart and axis OY - I don't need it.

Comment: You can reduce the padding to minimal level as you wish.
If you dont want to cutoff the point and not to use padding, take a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468108/adding-c3-js-padding-without-cutting-off-graph

Comment: Thank you, it helps with circles, but unfortunately not with text.